# Why doesn't @e work properly with these commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a minecraft gun using a carrot on a stick, but I can't seem to be able to apply an `instant_damage` effect on the entity successfully. In fact, targeting the block below (or 1 block away, since I used the `@e[distance=..1]`) the entity works, yet targeting the entity itself does not

```
execute at @a[scores={gun=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:'"Gun"'}}}}] run summon minecraft:area_effect_cloud ~ ~1.8 ~ {Duration:100,Tags:['gun1']}
execute as @e[tag=gun1] at @s rotated as @p[distance=..2] run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
execute as @e[tag=gun1] at @s if block ^ ^ ^1 air run tp @s ^ ^ ^1
execute as @e[tag=gun1] at @s if block ^ ^ ^1 air run particle minecraft:crit ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0 1 force @a
```

This is mainly where the problem is I believe:

```
execute as @e[tag=gun1] at @s unless block ^ ^ ^1 air run effect give @e[distance=..1] minecraft:instant_damage 1 1 false
execute as @e[tag=gun1] at @s unless block ^ ^ ^1 air run kill @s
scoreboard players set @a gun 0
```